# CSS - overflow height and width, and word-wrap

Tags: css, overflow, word-wrap

I have problems with making a list of items with defined height and width to show properly in IE. In IE the overflows does not work for neither height nor width, and in chrome only the height of the box gets messed up, and the overflow to the right is hidden as expected.

I run a jquery script to truncate the overflowing text so it will fit in heigth. This script does not work in ie since the scrollheight is always the same as the height. However, in Chrome the text is not wrapped properly if one of the lines are overflowed to the right(width), so I tried adding the `word-wrap` to the css with no effect.

I've been working on this issue in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GWah/10/), and all the details of the issue should be available there.

I've tested with IE9 and Chrome 24.

Comment: #1 rule - don't style the list. Style the CONTENTS of the list. See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was removing the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` on the children. This way both the `word-wrap` and the overflow works on both IE and Chrome. Also, the javascript has been edited to compare the height with its parents height. This requires the parent to have a specified height and oveflow to be hidden to work.

I've edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GWah/16/).

Edit:
One minor note however: this prevents the text from being centered vertically. I'm working on a fix for this now...

Edit: 
Ok, so the solution to center the text in the list-items vertically was not a nice one, and not one I'm proud of. I changed my javascript to add css rules directly on the elements. See the fiddle